# How to use javascript in Acumatica?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cloud, erp, acumatica

I have do some extension and I need to using javascript to add new record into Acumatica Grid Control without callback to server. Do you have any suggest for this?
Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Acumatica highly discourages making any changes on client side (in browser). They do not support extensions to client side. If you make changes on client prepare for pain on every upgrade.

I suggest you consider implementing your code on server side with a callback.

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn off callback during adding the line you must simply add the following code into .aspx page inside PXGrid tag

```
<Mode InitNewRow="false" />
```

To add a new row on the client, you should write something like this:

```
window.px_alls["gridID"].addNewRow();
```

To to turn off "add new" callback on the client, you should write:

```
window.px_alls["gridID"].levels[0].initNewRow = false;
```